# mvc DropDownListFor after selection changed make TextBoxFor required field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I developing mvc web application. In this I have one dropdown. There are some values in `DropDownList`. Here is my code

```
if (commentTypes != null && commentTypes.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Type</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.CommentType, new SelectList(commentTypes, "Title", "Title"), new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Add / View Comments</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.Comments, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 1000, rows = "5"})
        <i class="text-warning">Max. 1000 characters allowed</i>            
    </div>
</div>
```

There is one value in dropdown i.e. `OTHER` When user select this value I want to add the `required = "required"` property to `@Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.Comments` and want to add `*` to `Add / View Comments` which is like `Add / View Comments *`.  I am not getting How can I implement this? Can someone help me?

### Edit

I tried this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.CommentType, new SelectList(commentTypes, "Title", "Title"), new { @id = "ddlComments", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "ddlCommentChangefunc(this.value,'" + commentName + "')" })

<script>   
function ddlCommentChangefunc(val, commentName) {      
    if (val == commentName)
    {
        $('#cmtTxtBox').prop('required', true);
        $('#lbladdView').text('Add / View Comments *');
    }
    else {
        $('#cmtTxtBox').prop('required', false);
        $('#lbladdView').text('Add / View Comments');
    }
}
</script>
```

It's working fine. But the issue is in first value in dropdown. If the first value is `OTHER` then it doesn't show me required. How can I show for first and other values also?

### Edit

I tried this

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "input[type='reset']", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $("frmEditor")[0].reset(); $("ddlComments").trigger("change"); });

$(document).ready(function () { $('#ddlComments').change(); });

$('#ddlComments').change(function () {        
    var value = $(this).val().toString().toUpperCase();

    if (value == '@ViewBag.Other_commentTypes') {
        $('#cmtTxtBox').prop('required', true);
        $('#lbladdView').text('Add / View Comments *');
    }
    else {
        $('#cmtTxtBox').prop('required', false);
        $('#lbladdView').text('Add / View Comments');
    }
});

function ddlCommentChangefunc(val, commentName) {
    if (val.toString().toUpperCase() == commentName) {
        $('#cmtTxtBox').prop('required', true);
        $('#lbladdView').text('Add / View Comments *');
    }
    else {
        $('#cmtTxtBox').prop('required', false);
        $('#lbladdView').text('Add / View Comments');
    }
}
</script>
```

But I don't want to hard code this `OTHER`. In mvc I have declare `var commentName` this variable. I want to pass this.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery

```
$('#Comments').change(function(){
   if($(this).val()=='OTHER')
      $(this).prop('required',true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But it doesn't work while it loads for first time. If I select the value from dropdown then it works.

Comment: Ok, trigger this event. $('#Comments').change();

Comment: you mean I need to trigger event in `@onchange = $('#Comments').change();` right?

Comment: Well, @onchange = ... - it's the place where you hook change event, right? You should trigger it somewhere else, i.e. in $(document).ready(function(){ $('#Comments').change(); });

Comment: On my page there on reset button if I select value from dropdown and click on reset again the same situation occurred if there first value is 'OTHER' then it doesn't make text box to required.

Comment: You can put this value into ViewBag in your controller, then check in your javascript agains this value, like

var value = $('#ddlComments').val();
    if (value == '@ViewBag.OTHER') {...

Comment: @ViewBag is working fine. Now I don't need to use hard coded OTHER. But one issue is there on my partialview I have two one is `save` and other is `reset`. Suppose in dropdown I have two values 1: `OTHER` and 2: `Rej-Member Not Found`. If I select `2` and click on reset button dropdown list show `1` value i.e. `OTHER`. But my textareafor box isn't show me mandatory. first time it work fine. but if I click on reset it doesn't work.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("form")[0].reset();  
  $("select").trigger("change");
});

Comment: About hardcoding: I meant, when you initialize your ddl in your controller, just put the first value in ViewBag, and check against it in your JS

Comment: `form` and `select` is the id of `form` and `dropdownlist` right?

Comment: Actually I have `Ajax Form`.

Comment: Yep, "form" and "select" are your ajax form and ddl

Comment: I paste this line above the ` $(document).ready` function. But not working.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Validation after reset?
Look into your generated markup. Did it find the value from ViewBag in your JS?
Could you copy-paste your generated HTML into jsfiddle and give us the link, so that we could see what's happened?

Comment: Yes it's validation after reset.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use following solution from https://foolproof.codeplex.com/ .. Download the solution and include js files in following order.

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/libs/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In your model

```html
 [RequiredIf("CommentType", Operator.EqualTo, "OTHER")]
 public string Comments { get; set; }
```

You will have to include the reference to **MVC Foolproof Validation.dll** you can download the dll from the same location.

You can override default message as well

```
 [RequiredIf("CommentType", Operator.EqualTo, "OTHER", ErrorMessage = "Required because of OTHER")]
 public string Comments { get; set; }
```